# Is it possible to intercept a matlab save() bytestream

Tags: serialization, matlab, save

In matlab it is possible to write matlab objects, or even the entire workspace, to a file using the matlab save() call. I would like to intercept the bytestream and postprocess it before it goes to a file, is this possible? Alternatively, is it possible to specify the filedescriptor that the bytestream is written to instead of the filename that usually goes into the save() call as an argument.

Note that I'm not looking for an alternative way to write a file in matlab, I know I can fopen() a file and write whatever I want, but the point is that I want to (re)use the object serialization that is internal to the save call, not invent my own again.

An analog question would of course arise for the load() call, but in that case intercepting the bytestream before it goes into the deserialization process, but I guess if it is possible for save() the solution to the load() problem will follow naturally.

A few clarifications:

1. I'm not looking at a new way to serialize matlab data, it already exists and the whole point of the exercise is to use the existing serialization in the save() call so that 1) I don't need to start updating the serialization code for new types of objects in newer versions of matlab, or heaven forbid people start using custom OOP objects, and 2) I can still easily use existing code to read in mat files, such as for example scipy's support for mat files.
2. The stream must not get out to a file or anything before post-processing, the idea is encryption for security, writing the stream out plain to a file completely undermines that purpose.

Complications:

- It seems that the functionality used in the `save` function in matlab isn't just a regular sequential write. Examining the object code of the libraries it seems that the save function is implemented using `matPutVariable` (previously called `matPutArray`) which writes a given variable of type `mxArray*` out to a file of type `MATFile*` opened with `matOpen`. The problem here is the following text in the description of `matPutVariable`:

  > If the `mxArray` does not exist in the MAT-file, the function appends it to the end. If an `mxArray` with the same name exists in the file, the function replaces the existing `mxArray` with the new `mxArray` by rewriting the file.

  This means that the `matPutVariable` function will have to seek through the file, obviously seeking will not be possible when pipes are used, so using pipes to implement our processing of the bytestream is not possible when using this existing serialization functionality.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to accomplish? Are you wanting to postprocess the data then let it continue on to be written to the file, or do you want to postprocess it and direct it elsewhere?

Comment: @gnovice it would be fine if the postprocessed bytestream goes to file, though if I can redirect the bytestream (unpostprocessed) I can direct it to a postprocessing facility. So in short I either want to postprocess the bytestream inline, or I want to redirect the bytestream unpostprocessed.

Comment: you can always just use the default SAVE behavior then read the created file as a stream of bytes using FREAD..

Comment: @Amro No can do, the whole point of this is to post-process it before it goes to anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After brooding on this for several months, I'm going to say, no, this is not possible. At least, not without hardcore non-portable binary/ELF hacking.

Answer (score 5):

How about using a virtual filesystem? On Windows there is a commercial library called BoxedAPP SDK that allows you to create a virtual file that is only visible to the creating process (possibly children also). You would probably have to make a MEX to interface the library. First you would create the virtual file and then you could use the save command in matlab with the same filename. Then you can read the serialized .mat bytestream using normal fopen/fread functions in the matlab and do what ever you wish with it. This would at least prevent the file getting created on the hard disk. I'm not sure though if the file or parts of it could get to the swap file in some situation as the file is actually created to the memory.

There seems to be also undocumented functions mxSerialize and mxDeserialize in libmx that you could use eg. by loadlibrary/calllib functions directly from matlab or by a wrapper mex. A bit of Googling revealed that the signature for these functions should be

```
mxArray* mxSerialize(const mxArray*);
mxArray* mxDeserialize(const void*, size_t);
```

and some tests revealed that mxSerialize() gets the matlab variable as argument and returns a serialized bytes as uint8 array. The mxDeserialize() transforms this uint8 array (1st argument) back to matlab object as return value. The 2nd argument for mxDeserialize seems to be the number of elements in the 1st argument. Using these undocumented functions is not though guaranteed to work in future because TMW might change the API.

Comment: +1 very nice. If anyone is interested, I found MEX-wrapper implementations here: [mxSerialize.c](http://code.google.com/p/fieldtrip/source/browse/trunk/src/mxSerialize.c) and [mxDeserialize](http://code.google.com/p/fieldtrip/source/browse/trunk/src/mxDeserialize.c)

Comment: another project wrapping the same functions: https://github.com/kyamagu/matlab-serialization/ . There was a mention in [a comment](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/improving-save-performance/#comment-200289) that there exit builtin functions (also undocumented) doing the same thing: `getByteStreamFromArray` and `getArrayFromByteStream`

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** (based on comments) Hmm, I guess my old answer doesn't help much then. I don't know how you would go about intercepting the bytestream, but I suppose one option you have (which is admittedly a little bit of a kludge) is to just *let* the [SAVE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/save.html) function create the file then immediately read the data from the file byte-wise, process it, and write it back to the file. Something like:

```
save('workspace.mat');
fid = fopen('workspace.mat','r');
byteData = fread(fid,inf,'*uint8');
fclose(fid);
%# ... Process byteData here ...
fid = fopen('workspace.mat','w');
fwrite(fid,byteData,'uint8');
fclose(fid);
```

---

**Old answer:**

For user-defined class objects, I believe what you're looking for is embodied in the overloaded [SAVEOBJ](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/saveobj.html) and [LOADOBJ](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/loadobj.html) methods, which are called on an object before saving it to or loading it from a file. When [saving or loading objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brzyll3.html) to or from .MAT files, you can use these methods to [modify the save/load process](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/br0lx_g.html) so that the objects can be formatted in different ways. However, I don't think you can do this for built-in data types, only for user-defined objects.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not talking about Matlab OOP, just regular old matrices and a couple structs

Comment: And I'm not looking to change the serialization process of the objects, in fact I want that to stay exactly as it is. But I want to post-process the resulting byte stream.

Comment: Sorry, still no dice, the stream mustn't go anywhere before post-processing.

Comment: @wich: Hmm, this one's tough. Oh well, back to the drawing board... ;)

Comment: that it is, I've been dreaming up all kinds of insane ideas, like for example interposing the open() syscall by linking in a library that provides an open() call of the same signature and returns a pipe to a post-processing facility. But mcc doesn't allow you to link in additional libraries and a mex doesn't help as that is dlopen()'d after libc has already been linked dynamically. Mutilating the resulting binary with say elfedit might provide a solution, but that makes it even more messy. And to top it all of the whole deal would be horribly platform dependent... :(

Answer (score 2):

For HG objects, you can intercept the save processing via the internal (modifiable) *.m files that are explained here:
http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/handle2struct-struct2handle-and-matlab-8/

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help me, talking regular old matrices and a couple structs here. I don't want to change the serialization, in fact I explicitly want to use save()'s serialization, it's just that I want to post-process the resulting byte stream before it goes to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably to write the mat file to a tmpfs/ramdisk and then encrypt it before saving it to disk. You sacrifice portability and rely on the OS to provide secure virtual memory, but if you can't even trust the local disk, you're probably not going to be able to achieve satisfactory security.

By the way, why exactly are you unable to trust the local disk at all, even to the extent that you can't put your temporary file in a directory with permissions set to only allow access for the user owning the matlab process (and root)? Are you trying to implement a DRM system?

Comment: The system handles confidential data that the operator should not be privy to. And yes I understand that as long as the process is run by a user that the operator has control over it will never be truly secure, but since this is not a situation I can change at the moment all I can do is make it as hard as possible.

Comment: You may also be able to use a named pipe for communication, but on Windows named pipes are hard to work with. On unix systems, you can use `mkfifo` to create the pipe, and then have your encrypter open it read-only before MATLAB saves to it. Any process trying to listen in on that pipe will cause the encrypter to not receive the bytes the other listener gets, which you would at least be able to detect afterwards.

Comment: yes, a named pipe is one of the "insane ideas" which I referred to earlier, but I discarded it as it is too easy to eavesdrop on as well as being horribly platform dependent. And actually in Windows it would work better as you could actually prevent the pipe being opened for reading by another process as a named pipe is attached to a particular process and not just a device node in the file system.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you encrypt the content of variables instead ?

With `whos`, you get a list of all your variables in alphabetic order. For each one, you generate a mask of the same size with your encryption algorithm and you replace the "true" value by itself XOR the mask. To finish, you save the encrypted variables using `save`. The name and size of your variables are visible but that's probably not critical (if necessary, you can crypt names too).

Proceed the same way to load.

Comment: That would be very involved and cumbersome, you'd need to make all kinds of different cases for different data structures, let alone when people start using custom oop stuff. I'd sooner implement my own serialize/deserialize, this really needs to be done post-serialization.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getByteStreamFromArray` and `getArrayFromByteStream` for serialisation/deserialisation. You can modify the resulting bytes before you write them to a file

```
% A cell array of several data types
>> byteStream = getByteStreamFromArray({pi, 'abc', struct('a',5)});  % 1x312 uint8 array
>> getArrayFromByteStream(byteStream)
ans = 
    [3.14159265358979]    'abc'    [1x1 struct]
```

As explained on http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/serializing-deserializing-matlab-data

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do something like the following:

```
%# serialize objects into a byte array using Java
bout = java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
out = java.io.ObjectOutputStream(bout);
out.writeObject( rand(3) )                %# MATLAB matrix
out.writeObject( num2cell(rand(3)) )      %# MATLAB cell array
out.flush()
out.close()
bout.close()
b = bout.toByteArray();                   %# vector of type int8

%# perform processing on `b` ...

%# write byte[] stream to file
save file.mat b
```

Then in the opposite direction, you simply load the saved MAT-file, reverse whatever processing you performed, and deserialize the stream of bytes to recvover the original objects.

```
%# load MAT-file
load file.mat b
b = typecast(b,'int8');                   %# cast as int8 just to be sure

%# undo any processing on `b`...

%# deserialize
in = java.io.ObjectInputStream( java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(b) );
X1 = double( in.readObject() )            %# recover matrix
X2 = cell( in.readObject() )              %# recover cell array
in.close()
```

Note that you would have to maintain variables meta-information on your own, such as their number and type (maybe you can save it inside the same MAT-file somehow), and use custom wrapper functions to take care of all marshaling, but you get the idea...

---

I also came across a couple of submissions on FEX that help in serializing/deserializing MATLAB types:

- [serialize](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12063-serialize)
- [Serialize/Deserialize](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29457)

Comment: As far as I can tell this will not serialize as in a "Mat file" as generated by save(). As mentioned in the question that is a requirement. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @wich: no this is using Java serialization and has nothing to do with MATLAB's MAT-files... The only other thing I can think of is to use the HDF5 format (as you can use it inside MATLAB or outside using any of the many libraries/interfaces available)

Answer (score 1):

I am also interested on this problem. I found some things, but nothing works:

- **matlab save stdio** you find this hidden feature, but it doesn't work
- **engGetArray/engPutArray** *"This routine allows you to copy a variable out of the workspace."*

Look at MAT files specification, maybe we can reproduce matlab serialization with a Mex file:

- http://www.eiscat.se/groups/Documentation/UserGuides/matlab4.pdf

#### Update:

I found something very interesting: run in Matlab console this command

```
edit([matlabroot '/extern/examples/eng_mat/matcreat.c']);
```

or this

```
edit([matlabroot '/extern/examples/eng_mat/matcreat.cpp']);
```

This is the documentation, how to compile it: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f14500.html

In my opinion it should be feasible to use STDOUT in `pmat = matOpen(file, "w");` command.

Comment: I don't think matOpen can be used to redirect the output to another file descriptor. `file` in this case is simply a string containging the file path.

Comment: Oh and `save stdio` doesn't appear to work in compiled matlab.

Comment: Maybe in Linux it's possible to use file string '/dev/stdout'

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: `mkfifo /tmp/fifo` -- This creates a FIFO, a filename that represents a pipe. Anything written into the pipe stays there until a process reads it back out of the pipe. The data never hits the disk.

Step 2: In one terminal, run this: `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -e -in fifo -out safe` -- This runs the OpenSSL program to encrypt with AES, 256 bit key, CBC mode (openssl supports a lot more cipher types and parameters, pick one that works for you, this is a safe default); `-a` Base64 encodes the output (which is nice for testing, but you can probably leave it off when you're really using it, Base64 causes a 4/3 size-increase); `-e` runs in encrypt mode, `-in fifo` specifies that the input file is named `fifo` (perhaps use the full path); `-out safe` specifies that the output file is named `safe` (again, perhaps use a full path). OpenSSL will sleep until data arrives in the pipe.

OpenSSL will prompt you for a passphrase when some data arrives on the pipe.

Test it out: run "echo foo > /tmp/fifo" in another terminal. See the password prompt in the first terminal, give it a password and confirm the password, then look at the contents of the file 'safe':

```
$ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -e -in fifo -out safe
# (in another terminal, "echo foo > fifo")
enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
Verifying - enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
$ cat safe
U2FsdGVkX18aWBw0Uz8N3SfrRg4PigL609F+HQPuc6o=
```

Test the other direction:

```
$ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -d -in safe
enter aes-256-cbc decryption password:
foo
```

Now, re-run the OpenSSL command from Step 2: `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -e -in fifo -out safe`, run your Matlab, and give `/tmp/fifo` to the `SAVE()` command.

There *is* a chance that Matlab will do something silly like delete *any* existing file with the given filename, in which case you will find your unencrypted data in a *regular* file named `/tmp/fifo`. So please test with some unimportant data first. But I hope Matlab is written with Unix tools in mind, and will simply write into the named pipe you give it.

Comment: This isn't possible. As I noted in the question, Matlab seeks in the file during the write, so pipes are out of the question. Also, it would open up an entry point in the file system which I don't want, way too easy to intercept with a man in the middle approach.

Comment: @wich, did you try the pipes? Most programs handle pipes gracefully, degrading to a very nice pipe-oriented approach. Furthermore, if you set the permissions on your pipe correctly (`chmod 600`), it will only be usable by you and the admin (with difficulty), who can **always** attach a debugger such as gdb, ltrace, or strace to your programs and read your data right out of memory. Honestly, debugging the program would probably be easier than intercepting the pipe.

Comment: Yes, I tried, it doesn't work. And yes, I know the data can never be 100% safe, hell the operator has physical access, so even if they did not have direct access to the running user, they could even use volatile memory forensics. But that's the bounds I have to work with. When using a point in the filesystem all that is needed is a generic tool to intercept a named pipe, when it all stays within the process at least one needs the right knowledge or a custom tool tailored to the specific implementation. And before you say anything, yes I know security through obscurity is no security.