# easiest way to serialize multi-dimensional array in MATLAB for database insertion?

Tags: matlab, serialization

I can't seem to find any standard functions for serializing data. I have a large 128x51 array that I need need to store in a single database field. Without some kind of serializing, things will be problematic.

Whats the best way to solve this? I don't use matlab quite that much so I'm not familiar with standard procedures...

Comment: similar question: [Is it possible to intercept a matlab save() bytestream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807035/is-it-possible-to-intercept-a-matlab-save-bytestream) (a lot of useful answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to use the [TYPECAST](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/typecast.html) function to convert numeric values into UINT8 bytes (only works for full, non-complex numeric values).

Note that the matrix has to be reshaped into a vector prior to serialization, thus its size will also have to be separately stored (or even serialized using the same process):

```
%# sample matrix
M = rand(3,4);

%# convert
b_sz = typecast(size(M),'uint8');   %# serialized matrix size
b = typecast(M(:),'uint8');         %# serialized vector
```

Now you can store `b` and `b_sz` into the database as sequences of bytes (integers in the range `[0,255]`)

```
>> whos b b_sz
  Name       Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  b         96x1                96  uint8              
  b_sz      16x1                16  uint8
```

Next, when you retrieve those values from DB, you can convert them back to double values using the inverse procedure, and reshape the matrix to its original size:

```
MM = reshape(typecast(b,'double'), typecast(b_sz,'double'));

%# compare against original matrix
isequal(M,MM)
```

---

Optionally, if your database does not support array types, you can just convert the byte sequence as string, and store it in a VARCHAR type of field:

```
%# as string
str = sprintf('%d ',b);

%# recover bytes from string
b = uint8(str2num(str));
```

Comment: In fact, it seems to be what the [Serialize/Deserialize](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29457) submission on FEX is doing, only it handles more cases (all MATLAB datatypes including structures and cells)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if I'm grasping your question correctly, but have you tried looking at the reshape function? It reshapes the input matrix A into an m by n matrix:

```
B = reshape(A,m,n);
```

if you set m to 1, and n to (128*51), you are 'serializing' the data.

[MATLAB Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html)

Comment: -1 that doesn't help on its own, not if you care about preserving floating-point numbers exact precision