# Conversing struct object into binary in Matlab?

Tags: unit-testing, matlab

I need to get the binary presentation of structure for testing. The struct object can be like the below

```
a = 

    const: 1
    terms: {[1x1 struct]  [1x1 struct]}
```

I need something like this

```
assert(struct2bin64(a)=='3g439acahplrhph24'))
```

where I need to get the binary-or-equivalent presentation such as uint64 for testing.

**How can I convert a struct object for something that I can easily compare with assert?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with a `struct2bin` converter is that the question of what to convert it to cannot be answered uniquely. That `'const'` field you have there for example, contains a double precision number with a value of `1`. That double already consumes 64 bits, so `uint64` is not sufficient to contain the structure.

So, I think you mean a base-64 representation. In that case, you have a similar problem; how long would the string be? Although you could serialize the structure to base-64 and compare with *strcmp* to a pre-generated base64 string, what would be wrong with something along the lines of

```
assert(isequal(a, struct(...
    'const', 5,...
    'terms', {{struct('const', 6), struct('const' ,2.2)}}))...
);
```

e.g., explicitly re-create an anonymous copy of the exact structure you want?

If you *insist* on doing it the complicated way, you could use [this submission on the file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12907-xmliotools/content/base64encode.m), which allows you to convert a string to base64. Then use one submission of myself, [toString](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38566-string-representations-for-most-data-types), which will convert anything into a string, including structures. With these, you could do

```
assert(strcmp(base64encode(toString(a)), 'your_pre-generated_base64_string'))
```

but really, why on Earth would you want to? :)

Comment: I suspect the `64` he is referring to relates to [base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), not encoding into `uint64` types...

Comment: @Floris: same problem; how long would the base64-string be?

Comment: @Floris: plus the OP mentions `uint64` explicitly in the question :)

Answer (score 2):

You could save the struct to file - that's Matlab's way of showing you what the (compressed) binary representation is.  If you have a "reference file" already loaded in memory, you can then save the file, read it as binary, and compare.

```
referenceStruct = struct( 'field1', val1, 'field2', etc);
save('ref.mat', 'referenceStruct');
fid = fopen('ref.mat', 'rb');
refBinary = fread(fid, inf, 'uint8');
fclose(fid);
```

Now you convert the binary values to something that can fit in ASCII, e.g. with [these routines](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4341-encode-decode-ascii-binary).

But I have to agree with Rody - why go through the bother? This is horrible. You can create a reference structure, test with `isequal`, and be done. Of course we're not even talking about the dangers of comparing `double` types for equality... that's for another time and another question.

Comment: related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6261884/97160 (and follow the links in the comments)

Answer (score 1):

The [unit test framework](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-unit-test-framework.html) included in MATLAB in R2013a contains the ability to recursively compare struct arrays. This solution is much more strict than using isequal because isequal ignores things like sparsity and class (struct of int8's vs struct of doubles). For example, the following comparison passes:

```
assert(isequal(struct('const', 5), struct('const', int8(5))));
```

However, it fails in the unit test framework:

```
>> testCase = matlab.unittest.TestCase.forInteractiveUse;
>> testCase.verifyEqual(struct('const', 5), struct('const', int8(5)))
Interactive verification failed.

---------------------
Framework Diagnostic:
---------------------
verifyEqual failed.
--> NumericComparator failed.
    Path to failure: <Value>.const
    --> Classes do not match.

    Actual Class:
        double
    Expected Class:
        int8

Actual struct:
        const: 5
Expected struct:
        const: 5
>>
```

With this additional strictness I do not see the need to convert the structure to binary, in which case you are simply going to lose any chance of having meaningful diagnostics.